# push to viewcontroller from UIView class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am having HomeViewController with 5 Tabs. Each tab has UIView class to show its detail.
In one tab I have to push another viewcontroller say DetailViewcontroller from CollectionView's Cell click.
I have tried many things like:

1. make the method in parent class of UIView and push the viewcontroller
2. use Delegate method and push

But nothing has worked for me. Here is my code.

```
wish = [[WishListViewController alloc]init];
[home presentViewController:wish animated:YES completion:nil];<br>
```

also try

```
- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController
{
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    while (topVC.presentedViewController)
    {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topVC;
}
```

How can I push the view controller from UIView class.?

Comment: Your code is Objective-C?, this is your real code?, please put your real code to try help you

Comment: @ios Developer... have you got solution...pls post it here

Answer (score 0):

Your tab needs to have a navigation controller with a UIViewController as the root and then just push any new UIViewController, for example see image, also there is a old but good tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's [website](https://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1). Good luck.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can not push viewcontroller from view. Please explain what you needs to perform. From the question I can assume that you need to develop a tab based application. In that case you should add a tab bar to your project, then you just need to add viewcontroller on tab items.

Comment: yes. i am added viewcontrollers in the tabs. but i also need to add uiview in each viewcontroller at runtime. and from that uiview need to navigate different viewcontrollers.i knw it's not possible but still any other way which perfome this task?

Comment: in that case, if you are adding a view on a controller, then you need to push another view controller from the parent controller, not from view.